# date wise multiple product data for multiple employee in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am stuck in a problem to get date wise multiple product data for multiple employee doesn't know how to solve this.

Main Table / Table1 - In this Amount is Constant always 1

```
SNo | EmpName | LblCode | DateOfSour | ProdType | Amount
1   |  Emp1   |   001   | 2019-01-01 |  Prod1   | 1
2   |  Emp1   |   001   | 2019-01-01 |  Prod2   | 1
3   |  Emp2   |   002   | 2019-01-02 |  Prod1   | 1
4   |  Emp1   |   001   | 2019-01-01 |  Prod1   | 1
5   |  Emp3   |   003   | 2019-01-01 |  Prod2   | 1
6   |  Emp2   |   002   | 2019-01-03 |  Prod2   | 1
```

The Desire result

```
EmpName |DateOfSour| LblCode |  Prod1 | Prod2 | Prod3 |DateOfSour|  Prod1 | Prod2 | Prod3 |DateOfSour|  Prod1 | Prod2 | Prod3 |
Emp1    |2019-01-01|   001   |    2   |   1   |   0   |2019-01-02|    0   |   0   |   0   |2019-01-03|    0   |   0   |   0   |
Emp2    |2019-01-01|   002   |    0   |   0   |   0   |2019-01-02|    1   |   0   |   0   |2019-01-03|    0   |   1   |   0   |
Emp3    |2019-01-01|   003   |    0   |   1   |   0   |2019-01-02|    0   |   0   |   0   |2019-01-03|    0   |   0   |   0   |
Total   |2019-01-01|         |    2   |   2   |   0   |2019-01-02|    1   |   0   |   0   |2019-01-03|    0   |   1   |   0   |
```

i tried a Below Code But Failed to this but This is as far as could reached to this format 
Code i used:

```
SELECT  
      DateOfSour,
      ISNULL(EMPName,'Total')as EmpName,
      IsNULL(LblCode,'') as LblCode ,
      SUM(CASE WHEN ProdType='Prod1' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) as Prod1,
      SUM(CASE WHEN ProdType='Prod2' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) as Prod2,
      SUM(CASE WHEN ProdType='Prod3' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) as Prod3,
FROM Table1
  WHERE DateOfSour between('2019-01-01') and ('2019-01-03') 
  GROUP BY DateOfSour, GROUPING SETS((EMPName,LblCode), ())
```

I use SQL Server 2008.

> Edit 1: this is just an example for two days i wanted it for any
>   random date given

Answer (score 0):

You need more columns.  Something like this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(EMPName, 'Total') as EMPName,       
       COALESCE(LblCode, '') as LblCode ,
       '2019-01-01' as DateOfSour1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DateOfSour = '2019-01-01' AND ProdType = 'Prod1' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) as Prod1_1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DateOfSour = '2019-01-01' AND ProdType = 'Prod2' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) as Prod2_1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DateOfSour = '2019-01-01' AND ProdType = 'Prod3' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) as Prod3_1,
       '2019-01-02' as DateOfSour2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DateOfSour = '2019-01-02' AND ProdType = 'Prod1' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) as Prod1_2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DateOfSour = '2019-01-02' AND ProdType = 'Prod2' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) as Prod2_2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DateOfSour = '2019-01-02' AND ProdType = 'Prod3' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) as Prod3_2
FROM Table1
WHERE DateOfSour IN (''2019-01-01', '2019-01-02') 
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS((EMPName, LblCode), ())
```

Comment: This works fine but what if it is for more than 2 dates, it is not possible to add columns for each date.

Comment: @ultranoobkiller . . . If it is more than two dates, then it is a different question.  This answers the question that you actually asked.  If you have a *different* question, ask it as a *new* question.

Comment: Sorry i wasn't clear, can u please help me to get result for more than 2 dates.